# Customize 0x API to get more details

Tags: 0x

we are testing the 0x API our goal is to get more details, like the top 5 rates along with the best rate also routing information
can anyone point me in the right direction, please
by default, it only gives the best rate and not the 2nd or 3rd best.

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, you need to fork 0X API and implement the way to fit your needs, docs on 0x API don't mention ways to customize the way you want.

If I was you I would go start checking these routes https://github.com/0xProject/0x-api/blob/master/src/routers/swap_router.ts and start check the endpoint that calculates the rates and customize it to also add more rates.